# Inheritence of interfaces realizations on Kotlin

Tags: class, kotlin, inheritance, interface

At first i have to make two interfases. Both would have many implementations. And then i need interface, that would be inheritated from both random implementations of first two interfaces. Example on "cars that are crafted from carcase and engine".

The first two interfaces:

```
interface Carcase {
   val aerodynamics: Float 

   fun getAD(){return aerodynamics}
}

interface Engine {
   val power: Int

   fun getP(){return power}
}
```

And some of theuir implementations:

```
class BMV: Carcase {
    override val aerodynamics: Float = 1.0f
}
class Volvo: Carcase {
    override val aerodynamics: Float = 1.5f
}


class V1: Engine {
    override val power: Int = 10
}
class V3: Engine {
    override val power: Int = 20
}
class V5: Engine {
    override val power: Int = 30
}
```

And now interface that inheritate both implementations, whatever ones:

```
// idk if it working or allowed at all
interface Car<S,T>: Carcase, Engine {
    fun getSpeed{
        return( S.getAD() * T.getP() )  //?????
    }
}
```

As result i want to type in main code something like that:

```
val car1 = Car<BMW, V1>
val car2 = Car<Volvo, V5>
```

And it should make something like:

```
val s1 = car1.getSpeed() // 1.0f * 10
val s2 = car2.getSpeed() // 1.5f * 30
```

**Question**: How to make this inheritetion correctly?

I can get both straight answer or some books (with links on needed pages), because i dont know even what to google about that.

Answer (score 1):

Seems it's easier to just make classes and then declare variables of that class:

```kotlin
class Carcase(val aerodynamics: Float)

class Engine(val power: Int)

val BMV = Carcase(1.0f)

val Volvo = Carcase(1.5f)
```

And then your `Car` class becomes:

```kotlin
class Car(val case: Carcase, val engine: Engine) {
    fun getSpeed =  case.aerodynamics * engine.power
    
}
```

Comment: Okay, but it seems like i need to create instances of Carcase and Engine outside of car (or in it constructor), but that is not exactly what i want. I want to describe all variants of both interfaces in it realizations without creating its instances, and create cumulative parameters of both depending on _carcase_ and _engine_ that I choose in _Car_ constructor.